# gdalcubes create_image_collection() results in R session Abort after interrupting it

Tags: r, session, abort

I want to use gdalcubes in order to create a datacube structure in R from locally safe remote sensing data time series. I have tried it on a big data set (~5GB) and the create_image_collection function started, but the process was very slow (11% after three hours) and I couldn't barely use my computer while it was runinng. Therefore, I interrupted the process in a very brutal way (holding power button).
This seems to have been a big mistake, because now the function always result in a 'R Session Abort', even when calling it on a much smaller dataset. I unistalled gdalcubes and reinstalled it, but nothing has changed.
Are there any files I could delete or directories to reset in order to make it work again? I fear there are some files left anywhere in the directory structure that may cause this, but I really don't have no idea of these structures.
Thanks for any help, I really need this package!
See question on GitHub: https://github.com/appelmar/gdalcubes_R/issues/78

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RPostgres_1.4.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9       rstudioapi_0.14  raster_3.6-14    knitr_1.41       hms_1.1.2        rappdirs_0.3.3   bit_4.0.5        here_1.0.1       lattice_0.20-45  rlang_1.0.6     
[11] fastmap_1.1.0    blob_1.2.3       tools_4.2.2      grid_4.2.2       xfun_0.36        png_0.1-8        terra_1.6-53     cli_3.4.1        DBI_1.1.3        htmltools_0.5.4 
[21] ellipsis_0.3.2   yaml_2.3.6       digest_0.6.31    bit64_4.0.5      rprojroot_2.0.3  lifecycle_1.0.3  Matrix_1.5-1     codetools_0.2-18 vctrs_0.5.1      evaluate_0.20   
[31] rmarkdown_2.20   sp_1.5-1         compiler_4.2.2   reticulate_1.26  jsonlite_1.8.4   pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of research and trying around, the simple solution was to install R 4.1.0. In this version of R the package is working perfectly. R session Abort can often be solved by this, probably.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).